# proving with sequences that in a compact space $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty }F_{n}\neq \varnothing $

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space then every descending sequence $F_{n}$ non-empty and closed sunsets of $X$ has $$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty }F_{n}\neq \varnothing. $$

my solution :

(i know there is a different one where you take $X=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty }F_{n}^{c}$ but my first thought was this)

since $F_{n}$ non-empty and closed and also $F_{n}\supseteq F_{n+1}$ $\Rightarrow $ $\bigcap_{n=1}^{m }F_{n}\neq \varnothing $

now  since $X$ is compact and $F_{n}$  closed we know that $F_{n}$ is also compact therefore exist $x_{(1)_{k_{n}}} \in F_{1}$

$x_{(1)_{k_{n}}}\rightarrow x_{1} \in F_{1}$

$x_{(2)_{k_{n}}}\rightarrow x_{2} \in F_{2}$  and $ x_{2} \in F_{1}$

$ \vdots $

If I continue like that  there will be at least one   element let say it $x$  in $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty }F_{n} $ and we showed that its non-empty.

Is this proof mathematically ok? Or this isn't correct(please explain).

Question: how many elements can be on the $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty }F_{n} $ infinite ,
finite or just one?

Comment: How do you justify the assertion “If I continue like that there will be at least one element let say it $x$ in $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty F_n$”? How do you know that?

Comment: From my algorithm $F_{1}\cap F_{2} $ will have at least one element $x_{2}$ if i do this every time the $\bigcap $ will be at least the last limit or this doesn't work?

Comment: I have no idea about the meaning of “last limit” here. It is an infinite sequence; it has no last element. Besides, I also don't know what you mean when you state that “exist $x_{(1)_{k_n}}\in F_1$”.

Comment: There is a subsequence $x_{1}$  on $ F_{1}$ and because its compact it has a limit point on $ F_{1}$

Comment: Why do you need that? Why don't you just say that $x_1$ is an element of $F_1$?

Comment: I now see I don't really need that, if i do that then this proof will be ok?

Comment: No. Again: what is the “last limit”?

Comment: That was my mistake since my algorithm is infinity there will be no last limit , what i really meant is if $x_{n}\epsilon F_{n } $ then its also belong to $ F_{n-1 } $ and $ F_{n-2 } $.... and $ F_{1 } $    same thing for $x_{n+1 }$ and it keeps going

Comment: So, I suppose that you agree that your attempt doesn't work. I can post my comments as an answer, if you want it.

Comment: Yes if you could do that  I would appreciate that , thanks for the clarifications , i guess i got confused .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :** Take an element $x_k$ in each of the $F_k$. The sequence $(x_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}^*}$ is a sequence in a compact, therefore there exists $\varphi : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ strictly increasing such that $(x_{\varphi(k)})_{k \in \mathbb{N}^*}$ converges to an element $x \in X$. Try to show that $$x \in \bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} F_i$$

Comment: Yea this look a way better version of what I was thinking of, I will try to answer this tomorrow (and post it here) because I don't have enough time right now .what about my question thought that means that there can be a finite number of elements on the bisection?

Comment: @PetrosK what you wrote is not very clear. I understand that you can take $x_1 \in F_1$, $x_2 \in F_1 \cap F_2$, $x_3 \in F_1 \cap F_2 \cap F_3$, and so on, but the fact that you can "take the limit" and get an element in all the $F_i$ is not clear... In particular, you should use *at this point* that $X$ is compact, otherwise the result is not true. Think about $F_i = [i, +\infty)$ in $\mathbb{R}$. They are closed, decreasing, but their intersection is empty.

Comment: Yes that was a perfect example  I was looking for on why we need the compactness i see now we need it to be bounded as well.